# Regular Expression to Match All Enclosed '' (2 Single Quotes)

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a **regex** that will provide me with **capture groups** for each set of 2 single quotes (`''`) within the single-quoted strings (`'string'`) that are part of a comma-separated list.  For instance the string `'tom''s'` would have a single group between the `m` and the `s`.  I've come close but keep getting tripped up by either erroneously matching up with the enclosing single quotes or with only capturing some of the 2 single quotes within a string.

**Example Input**

```
'11','22'',','''33','44''','''55''','6''''6'
```

**Desired Groups (7, shown in parens)**

```
 '11','22(''),','('')33','44('')','('')55('')','6('')('')6'
```

For context, what I'm ultimately attempting to do is replace these 2 single quotes within the comma-separated sequence of strings with another value in order to make subsequent parsing easier.

Note also that commas may be contained within the single quoted strings.

Comment: What is the regex flavor?

Comment: Python.  (?<!,|^)('')(?!,|$) is close ... but misses the first group due to the comma.  See: https://regex101.com/r/mX2sO7/2.

Comment: Ok, I will post an answer showing how to achieve the ultimate goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot match the double single quotes like that with Python `re` module. You can just match the single-quoted entries and capture the inner part of each entry, and using  a lambda, replace the `''` inside with a mere `.replace`:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r"'([^']*(?:''[^']*)*)'")
test_str = "'11','22'',','''33','44''','''55''','6''''6'"
print(p.sub(lambda m: "'{}'".format(m.group(1).replace("''", "&")), test_str))
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/SvlHs9), output: `'11','22&,','&33','44&','&55&','6&&6'`

The regex is [`'([^']*(?:''[^']*)*)'`](https://regex101.com/r/dL6qO0/1):

- `'` - opening `'`
- `(` - Capture group #1 start
- `[^']*`  - zero or more non-`'`
- `(?:''[^']*)*`  - 0+ sequences of `''` followed with 0+ non-`'`
- `)` - Capture group #1 end
- `'` - closing `'`

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks for the regex explanation and the Python code!